# npm i stuck on "idealTree: timing idealTree Completed in XXXXms"

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, command-line-interface

I've been trying to install dependencies in my nextjs project.
Upon running `npm i` in the project directory the command is stuck at "**idealTree: timing idealTree Completed in XXXXms**"

**`(Edit: The command is working in all directories except Downloads/)`**

I have tried the following as found in previous discussions about the topic:

1. Changing npm registry to http://
2. Turning off strict-ssl
3. Updating npm globally
4. Uninstalling & Reinstalling nodejs
5. Force cleaning node cache
6. Killing any node terminals running in background
7. Pointing PATH variables to right files
8. Deleting *node_modules/* and *package-lock.json*

But none seem to work

Node Version: `18.14.0`
NPM Version: `9.4.1`
OS: `Windows 11 Home Single-Language`
OS Version: `22H2`
OS Build: `22621.1194`

`package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": { 
    "next": "13.0.3",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0", 
  }
}
```

`npm i` log:

```
$ npm i -verbose
npm verb cli C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\aahan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
npm info using npm@9.4.1
npm info using node@v18.14.0
npm verb title npm i
npm verb argv "i" "--loglevel" "verbose"
npm verb logfile logs-max:10 dir:C:\Users\aahan\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-02-08T10_01_08_381Z-
npm verb logfile C:\Users\aahan\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-02-08T10_01_08_381Z-debug-0.log
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/next 1267ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/fibers 339ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/node-sass 299ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/react 196ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/react-dom 274ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/sass 317ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@next%2Fenv 410ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@next%2Fswc-android-arm64 540ms (cache revalidated)    
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/loose-envify 578ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/styled-jsx 613ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/use-sync-external-store 619ms (cache revalidated)      
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@next%2Fswc-linux-x64-gnu 626ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@swc%2Fhelpers 720ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@next%2Fswc-android-arm-eabi 716ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/scheduler 697ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@next%2Fswc-linux-arm64-gnu 735ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/postcss 760ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@next%2Fswc-freebsd-x64 758ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@next%2Fswc-linux-arm64-musl 808ms (cache revalidated) 
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@next%2Fswc-linux-arm-gnueabihf 822ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@next%2Fswc-darwin-arm64 840ms (cache revalidated)     
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@next%2Fswc-linux-x64-musl 844ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@next%2Fswc-win32-ia32-msvc 863ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@next%2Fswc-win32-arm64-msvc 880ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@next%2Fswc-win32-x64-msvc 1086ms (cache revalidated)  
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/caniuse-lite 1334ms (cache updated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@next%2Fswc-darwin-x64 2319ms (cache revalidated)      
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/source-map-js 192ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/picocolors 199ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/nanoid 210ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/tslib 220ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/client-only 1262ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/js-tokens 161ms (cache revalidated)
[#########.........] \ idealTree: timing idealTree Completed in 6984ms
```

Comment: Can you show the package.json?

Comment: @Anatoly attached the package.json code in the question itself.

Comment: Please add it as a formatted text. Also please indicate your OS

Comment: @Anatoly updated the question with the details

Comment: I tried your package.json (also it has a minor error - extra comma) and it works fine with the same versions of Node.js and npm on Windows 11. Could you indicate the exat path where this `npm i` does not work

Comment: @Anatoly turns out it's working everywhere except in `Documents/` directory

Comment: Once again: please show the exact full path of that `Documents` directory.

Comment: Initially it was `C:\Users\aahan\Documents\Coding\New_Project` but I tried `C:\Users\aahan\Documents\New Folder` not working there as well. Works everywhere else.

Comment: I tried the exact same path and it works fine. Did you try to uninstall Node.js and install it through nvm?

Comment: No, there must be some other issue since it's working everywhere else. I tried comparing permissions, couldn't find any difference. Guess I'd have to work somehwere else from now, Thanks anw!